# Center content of pseudo element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a `:before` pseudo element displayed on `:hover` of a particular element.

I'm using font awesome and want to vertically center the content of the `:before`, but vertical align, margins etc haven't been of much help.

Any ideas?

```
.tile:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;  
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "\f16b";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(219,127,8, 0.7);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.tile:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your relevant HTML and CSS, in order that we can, at least, visualise what's going on in your code?

Comment: I know worst-case-scenario, I can just use line-height: elementSize and it will vertically center it. But I'd prefer to solve this without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few potential suggestions for .tile:before  :

1 - use pixel value instead of 100% for height:

```
height: 100px;
```

2 - Make sure this is being displayed as an element that can ACCEPT margin, padding, etc.

```
display: block;
```

-or-

```
display: inline-block;
```

3 - I know you said you tried margins, but did you try padding-top?

```
padding-top: 20px;
```

4 - Try setting the overflow to hidden or visible. This often forces elements to behave "better."

```
overflow:hidden;
```

I would try all of these TOGETHER and see what happens.

Last, I might try setting a "top:" value since you have "position:absolute;" already.  Maybe try this in conjunction with "position:relative;" too.

```
top: 10px;
```

Really need all the code (HTML) to tell what would work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `:before` as the cover background to display on top of the **tile** element, and an `:after` with:

```
.tile:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* Both half of font-size */
  margin-left: -75px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Seemed to do the trick. Thanks all.